# GPS needs to be turned on even to ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION?

Tags: android, location

I get that fine locations come through GPS but if I am trying to get the coarse location by the network provider do I still need to have users GPS turned on?

EDIT:
I am attaching the code. Here is my MainActivity.java file.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int ACCESS_CODE = 1;
private TextView text;
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = findViewById(R.id.text);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, ACCESS_CODE);
    } else {
        updateLocation();
    }
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"hi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            text.setText("LATITUDE: "+latitude);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == ACCESS_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            updateLocation();
        }
    }
}

public void updateLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, ACCESS_CODE);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,5000,0,locationListener);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    locationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need the user’s GPS to be on while using ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.
When using the above, you get location updates from the network provider and is much less accurate than the fine location.

Comment: But my app is only working when I turn on GPS, even though I am requesting location from the NETWORK_PROVIDER. Also, I am requesting only ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. Please tell me what I am  missing here. Thanks.

Comment: I have added the MainActivity.java file. Please have a look.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I came across this though. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40532705 Hope this answers your question!